# Configuring Prettier for HTML files

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I've looked at Prettier's docs and have done a bunch of searches, but can't figure out how to configure angular html files the way I want. I want the elements to be on one line if it doesn't exceed the maximum characters for one line, but if it does exceed the max, then I want only one attribute per line, like you see below.

**Desired formatting:**

```
<app-example-component [attribute1]="attribute1"></app-example-component>

<app-example-component
  [attribute1]="attribute1"
  [attribute2]="attribute2"
  [attribute3]="attribute3"
  [attribute4]="attribute4"
></app-example-component>
```

This is what I am currently getting, and I find it to be difficult to read:

```
<app-example-component [attribute1]="attribute1" [attribute2]="attribute2"
  [attribute3]="attribute3" [attribute4]="attribute4"
  [attribute3]="attribute3" [attribute4]="attribute4"
  [attribute3]="attribute3"></app-example-component>
```

I am using VS Code and recently converted my Angular project to use ESLint instead of TSLint, but I wasn't using Prettier prior to that, so I don't know if that conversion is causing issues.

Here is my **.eslintrc.json** file. Maybe this is breaking Prettier for me somehow?

```
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "off",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit"
          }
        ],
        "id-blacklist": "off",
        "id-match": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code/User/settings.jsons:**

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "html.format.endWithNewline": true,
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the prettier works exactly as you described the desired solution. You can easily check it in [the playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEAeAhgB0wWjgD3QFtMAbOHSE6BGAAgG10YYAnASwCMBXeARgC6AXgA6IZmy684fMQD5UAeiy4CxMhSqYasOSKj6M2PIRLlKEalFqMJHHv2Fi7U-mNst70gExPxn1zhvdyYAhzgAZj8XcIiQmOkAFmiwpPklFRN1cy0dGD0DKBAAGhAITBh2aABnZFB0VlYIAHcABQaEWpR0Umb0AE9a0s5WdDAAazgYAGVMMfYoAHNkNm44UrgiTjgAEx3dgBl0Je50RbgAMQhWIgkF5e7eCBKQAAsYIlIAdVf2eGq5mA4NNOn92AA3P79ZDgapDEALapwVgwVqjRa3ZAAMx6SNKACtqvgAEKjCZTabEOAHBZwbG49YgQn4ab3cgARW4EHg9NIeJAc1YSNYMPenxemCaSK+o0wMMlcGF4LppQAjlz4Gjyl1xNUcNZdrsXqw4Or2Ca0WdMUgcXzGUiiOwVqw1qVqmy4JzuXSbQzSjB0JwvuwdjBXshvP7RuxSPcAMKWa0gRUAVhe3CRABVA11bfzwWsAJJQfawaZgDgVACCJemMH65F5-MlCxgwdD4aQfG8AAYAL59oA). Are you sure that `html` files are added to the prettier configuration of your IDE? Because usually by default, it's turned on only for js, ts, jsx, tsx files as far as I know.

So, check your .vscode/settings.json to contain next lines:

```json
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

**Update:**

This is your problem I think.

> ```json
>  "[html]": {
>      "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"   
>  }
> ```

Your code is not formatted according to the prettier rules.

Change this to

```json
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
```

as I've mentioned above

**Update 2:**

Also please check your "parser" option for the prettier configuration file. As long as you use prettier for multiple different files it should not be added on the top-level config. See documentation regarding this [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setting-the-parserdocsenoptionshtmlparser-option). In your case, it's allowed only inside "overrides"

Comment: I was originally ignoring html files, but as soon as I removed html from my prettierignore file, it started automatically reformatting to the ugly format I showed. I must have something set up wrong, but can't find what it is.

Comment: @Bryan, please, check my updated answer. However, sharing your `.vscode/settings.json` could be helpful.

Comment: @Bryan, you have incorrect formatter for your html files. Check my updated answer

Comment: @Bryan, did you have a chance to check? What shows your vscode when you select "Format Document" option in the context menu?

Comment: I thought for sure that that was the problem, but didn't work. Turned out I had to delete  "parser: 'typescript'" from prettier.config. Thanks for helping me track that down. If you add that to your answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Thank you. I've added it with appropriate explanation and reference to the docs